# How can I connect to a remote site on free webhosting?

Tags: c++

I am trying to connect to a website that 000webhost.com is hosting, but I am very new to c++ and socket so I don't understand how I can do this. Here Is what I have:

```
SOCKET Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
SockAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
cout << "Checking for updates... Please wait";
struct hostent *hEnt;
SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("23.23.251.76");
if (connect(Socket, (SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr)) != 0) {   
MessageBox::Show("Could not connect to server.", "Error",MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Exclamation);
system("pause");
}
string FullBuffer = "";
string VersionText = std::to_string(8+version.length());
string Header = string("POST /VersionChecker.php HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: MyWebsite.000webhostapp.com\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-Length: " + VersionText + string("\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\nVersion=") + version);
cout << Header;
```

The address "23.23.251.76" is the IP for 000webhostapp.com. With this code,  get the error "404 Not Found". Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The code you posted connects to a TCP server at `31.170.160.59` on port 80 and then prints a `POST` string to stdout. The address stated in your question is nowhere in your code. Where/how do you see the error message?

Comment: @gurka I fixed it. I see the code when I print the buffer for all of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is mostly what it says on the tin: you were able to connect to the server, but the resource you requested (`/VersionChecker.php`) was not found.

It's hard to say for sure, but I believe the first thing you should be looking at is whether the IP is correct, since it has been hardcoded rather than looked up with DNS. Notably, there's no guarantee that `MyWebsite.000webhostapp.com` is at the same address as `000webhostapp.com`, which your question content suggests.

Comment: The IP of MyWebsite.000webhostapp.com is an IPv6.

Comment: Only IPv6 (AAAA record), or does it have both IPv4 and IPv6 records (A and AAAA)?

If it only has an IPv6 address, you are getting a 404 because you are connecting to the wrong server, as the IPv4 address cannot be referring to the server that hosts `MyWebsite.000webhostapp.com`, which is the host you ask for in your HTTP request.

Comment: I have no idea what that means, but the IP is `2a02:4780:dead:4ef7::1`
I must be doing it wrong, as in the code, I am asking for the IP of 000webhostapp.com

Comment: Ok, so you're asking the server at `23.23.251.76` for `MyWebsite.000webhostapp.com`, but you are saying that the site is actually hosted by the server at `2a02:4780:dead:4ef7::1`.

The server you connect to with the hardcoded IP does not host the site you are looking for, and because of that it can't find the resources you are asking for, leading to a "404 Not Found" response.

Comment: No. The address `2a02:4780:dead:4ef7::1` is the address for MyWebsite.000webhostapp.com. The address `23.23.251.76` Is the address for 000webhostapp.com

Comment: Right, so you're connecting to `000webhostapp.com`, but then asking for `MyWebsite.000webhostapp.com` - these two domains look similar, but they may be hosted on different servers. Because of this, if you're connecting to `23.23.251.76`, you wont be able to get anything from `MyWebsite.000webhostapp.com`.

Comment: So how would I connect to `MyWebsite.000webhostapp.com`?

Comment: At the very least, use the correct IP address (which may be IPv6, and the appropriate types and APIs).

Better would be to look up the IP address of the domain at runtime, which will allow you to not worry about this issue in general. Perhaps `gethostbyname` is worth researching: https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/gethostbynameman.html